# Eclipse Mars not finding projects to import

Tags: eclipse, svn, import

I have been trying to import a project into Eclipse Mars, but the project import window insists that no projects exist within the folder I have selected.  The project in question has been written using Luna rather than Mars but I think it should still be compatible.  I have downloaded the project from an svn into the folder that I'm asking Eclipse to use to locate the project.  Below is a link to a screenshot.

[image: Mars not importing projects]

Comment: What kind of project are you trying to import?
Eclipse will look for .project files but is a common practice not to upload this file to code repository to make code independent from IDE. If you are importing a maven project select Import Existing Maven Project and eclipse will look for pom files